# Paint font awesome with two colors

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have this:

```
<span class="fa fa-beer"></span>
```

And I want to set the color of the icon with two colors (half each), for example red and green.

Is this possible using CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `background-clip:text` and a gradient on the icons background like this:

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/jcastillo/pen/OVrLEy?editors=110)**

```
.fa-beer {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(.5, blue), color-stop(1, orange));
    background-image: gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.5, blue), color-stop(1, orange));
    color:transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want with a bootstrap glyphicon, since they use the css property 'color' to change their background color. (they are considered fonts)

The only downside is that changing the color for font using a gradient appears to only be compatible using webkit, but this is how you would do it. (correct me if i'm wrong please).

Html:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
```

css:

```
i {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

and at the top of your html code inside your head element (if you dont know how to include boot strap just use the cdn)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Note:
you can add a % after a color to tell css how much space you want that color to take up.

ex: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green, green 150%);

you can also set the angle at which you want the gradient to appear on the marker.

ex: -webkit-linear-gradient(145deg, red, green, green 150%);